# Will the native buffer owned by BytesMut keep growing?

Tags: rust

Suppose I have a BytesMut object, and then keep writing data to its interior. Then split some frames out of it according to the frame segmentation format.

According to my idea, this memory is constantly reallocate out. So the question is, I can make its capacity smaller by constantly splitting, but at what point does it actually allocate contiguous memory to be freed?

If I keep taking data splits from the front, won't this memory usage get larger and larger? Or maybe I have a problem understanding that different BytesMut objects will have different native buffer when split, but how is this done?

```rust
#[test]
fn test_bytesmut_growth() {
    use bytes::{BufMut, BytesMut};
    let mut bm = BytesMut::with_capacity(16);
    for i in 0..10000 {
        bm.put(&b"1234567890"[..]);
        let front = bm.split();
        drop(front);
    }
    //println!("current cap={}, len={}", bm.capacity(), bm.len());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you split a `BytesMut` object into two, the two objects will still share the underlying reference-counted buffer. Here's an attempt at a visualization, containing a few implementation details. Before splitting:

```
 Underlying buffer, ref count 1
┌────────────────────────────────┐
│0123456789ABCDEFGHIJ            │
└▲───────────────────────────────┘
 │
 │   first
 │  ┌────────────┐
 ├──┤ptr         │
 │  │len: 20     │
 │  │cap: 32     │
 └──┤data        │
    └────────────┘
```

After calling `let second = first.split_off(10)`, we will get

```
 Underlying buffer, ref count 2
┌────────────────────────────────┐
│0123456789ABCDEFGHIJ            │
└▲─────────▲─────────────────────┘
 │         │
 │         └──────────┐
 │   first            │      second
 │  ┌────────────┐    │     ┌────────────┐
 ├──┤ptr         │    └─────┤ptr         │
 │  │len: 10     │          │len: 10     │
 │  │cap: 10     │          │cap: 22     │
 ├──┤data        │    ┌─────┤data        │
 │  └────────────┘    │     └────────────┘
 │                    │
 └────────────────────┘
```

Once we drop `first`, we will have

```
 Underlying buffer, ref count 1
┌────────────────────────────────┐
│0123456789ABCDEFGHIJ            │
└▲─────────▲─────────────────────┘
 │         │
 │         │
 │         │                 second
 │         │                ┌────────────┐
 │         └────────────────┤ptr         │
 │                          │len: 10     │
 │                          │cap: 22     │
 └──────────────────────────┤data        │
                            └────────────┘
```

If you now call `second.reserve(10)`, or call an operation that implicitly reserves, like writing more than fits in the current capacity, the `BytesMut` implementation can detect that `second` actually owns its underlying buffer, since the reference count is one. The implementation then may be able to reuse spare capacity in the buffer by moving the existing buffer contents to the beginning, so after `second.reserve(20)`, the result could look like this:

```
 Underlying buffer, ref count 1
┌────────────────────────────────┐
│ABCDEFGHIJ                      │
└▲───────────────────────────────┘
 │
 │   second
 │  ┌────────────┐
 ├──┤ptr         │
 │  │len: 10     │
 │  │cap: 32     │
 └──┤data        │
    └────────────┘
```

However, the conditions for this optimization to be applied are not guaranteed. The [documentation for `reserve()`](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/struct.BytesMut.html#method.reserve) states (emphasis mine)

> Before allocating new buffer space, the function will attempt to reclaim space in the existing buffer. If the current handle references a view into a larger original buffer, and all other handles referencing part of the same original buffer have been dropped, then the current view can be copied/shifted to the front of the buffer and the handle can take ownership of the full buffer, provided that the full buffer is large enough to fit the requested additional capacity.
>
> This optimization will only happen if shifting the data from the current view to the front of the buffer is not too expensive in terms of the (amortized) time required. The precise condition is subject to change; as of now, the length of the data being shifted needs to be at least as large as the distance that it’s shifted by. **If the current view is empty and the original buffer is large enough to fit the requested additional capacity, then reallocations will never happen.**

In summary, this optimization is only guaranteed if the reference count is one and the view is empty. This is the case in your example, so your code is guaranteed to reuse the buffer.

Comment: So great! What I'm trying to figure out is what was stated above. I intended to think it would use operations like reallocate to avoid moving data which is a relatively expensive operation. From your answer I understand that it will choose an appropriate actual to move the data so that it avoids the problem of the buffer moving backwards all the time.

Comment: @progquester Note that reallocating also involves moving the existing data to the new buffer, so you need to do that either way if the current buffer isn't big enough.

Comment: Got it, Thank you very much! And would you pelase help me with this question? It's been bothering me for a long time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73760798

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `BytesMut::split` 'Removes the bytes from the current view, returning them in a new BytesMut handle.
Afterwards, self will be empty, but will retain any additional capacity that it had before the operation.'

This is done by creating a new `BytesMut` (which is then owned by `front`) that contains exactly the items of `bm`, after which `bm` is modified such that it contains **only** the remaining empty capacity. This way, `BytesMut::split` doesn't allocate any new memory.

You then drop the `BytesMut` (owned by `front`), making it so that there is no view into the memory owned by the backing `Vec`, from the start of the `Vec` until the start of `bm`. When you then `put`, the implementation first checks if there is enough space **before** the view of `bm`, but still inside the backing `Vec`, and tries to store the data there.

Because the amount of memory you `put` is the same as the memory 'freed' by dropping `front`, the implementation is able to store that data before the view of `bm`, and no data is allocated.

Comment: Thank you very much. What I find very strange is what technique can be used to free part of a contiguous block of memory? It feels like realloc can't do it either

Comment: Freeing is just telling the memory allocator that a block of memory isn't used anymore, and that it may be used for something else. The contiguous block of memory would, in your case, probably just be RAM, and freeing is done by calling the OS's allocator, just like calling `free` in C.

Comment: @progquester If this answer has helped, can you please accept it?

Comment: I don't think this answer is accurate. Splitting off memory from a buffer only creates new views into the buffer. Dropping the new view does not free the underlying shared buffer, but rather only decreases its reference count.

Comment: @Heiko Ribberink some details is not clear util now, I do not known whether your answer is right or not. So please give me some time to investigate it. Thank you any ways.

Comment: @SvenMarnach you are correct, my answer wasn't accurate. I've read the implementation of `BytesMut` more carefully and edited my answer.