# How to cancel a tokio tcp connecting gracefully?

Tags: sockets, rust, rust-tokio, asyncsocket

When we connect to a remote host via tcp, it can be a time-consuming operation. And while waiting for a connection, the user may cancel the operation at any time.

When connecting using async tokio, `TcpStream::connect()` returns a `Future<TcpStream, io::Error>` object, assumed to be called `tcps_ft`.

There are two parts, one is the normal logic of the program, which should call `.awati()` on `tcp_ft` above, and the other part is the UI of the program, where the user wants to call `drop(tcps_ft)` if he clicks the cancel button. But this seems impossible to do, because both calls consume `tcps_ft`.

```rust
#[tokio::test]
async fn test_cancel_by_drop() {
    let addr = "192.168.1.100:8080";
    let tcps_ft = TcpStream::connect(addr);
    let mut tcps = tcps_ft.await.unwrap();

    // simulate user's operation.
    let cancel_jh = tokio::spawn(async move {
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
        drop(tcps_ft); // can not compile:: tcps_ft moved when await
    });

    // simulate user's program
    tcps.shutdown().await;
    cancel_jh.await;
}
```

So I considered using `Task` to do it, after all the `Task::abort()` function will not consume the `atjh: Future<JoinHandle>` object corresponding to this task. But I still can't call `atjh.await` before `abort()` returns synchronously, and in any case, await will consume the variable, making it impossible to call `abort()` asynchronously. (In other words, the call to `abort()` must be executed synchronously before `await`.)

```rust
#[tokio::test]
async fn test_cancel_by_abort() {
    let addr = "192.168.1.100:8080";
    let atjh = tokio::spawn(async move { TcpStream::connect(addr).await.unwrap() });

    // simulate user's operation.
    let cancel_jh = tokio::spawn(async {
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
        &atjh.abort();
    });

    // simulate user's program
    let mut tcps = atjh.await.unwrap(); // can not compile:: atjh moved when await
    tcps.shutdown().await;
    cancel_jh.await; 
}
```

Of course, one less direct way is to use callback functions. In my asynchronous connection task, when `connect().await` returns, the user's callback function is called to notify the user to call `atjh.await`.

But here the callback function is introduced again, and I know `await/async` itself is designed to solve the `callback hell` problem.

Further, for user-supplied asynchronous callback functions, the compiler may impose very many requirements, such as implementing `Send`, avoiding cross-thread safety issues, etc. This is certainly not something that `async` would like to encounter.

How can I do it asynchronously and gracefully to cancel this asynchronous connection process? Is there a suggested model to handle it?